# Custom tags in TYPO3 content

Tags: typo3

new here, and also new to TYPO3.

I need to put something like [imagebox, title='box1'] into content editor and that will be replaced by a text and image with some javascript effect (text and image are managed in the DB elsewhere, the tag is just for the placement in the page).

I've read that TYPO3 has a mechanism for adding custom tags and I managed to make them accepted in the RTE.
I tried instead of [imagebox.....    to use

```
<imagebox>box1</imagebox>
```

with something like this (copied from web):

```
tt_content.text.20.parseFunc.tags {
  imagebox < lib.parseFunc.tags.link
  imagebox = TEXT
  imagebox.value= replaced
#  imagebox =  PHP_SCRIPT
#  imagebox {
#    stripNL = 0
# Pass a parameter from Typoscript to a PHP script:
# UID of the page containing the SINGLE view of tt_news
#    id_singleView = 18
# Call the PHP script
#    file = fileadmin/scripts/imagebox_parser.php
#  }
}
lib.parseFunc.tags.imagebox < tt_content.text.20.parseFunc.tags.imagebox
```

should be able to replace content between tags.
I've commented call to php function just tried to get a text replacement for starters.
I've put that in the main root template Setup, but nothing is replaced.
I've also tried other examples from the web with no success.
Did anyone have situation like this?
Are there better approaches for that in TYPO3? (I'm using v7.6.23)

Any suggestion or hint is appreciated.

EDIT: using FSC on textmedia element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your examples are outdated. (the object PHP_SCRIPT is obsolete for a long time)

You might have a look at the documentation for your TYPO3 version:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/Functions/Parsefunc/

you also need to enhance the parsefunc where you need it. That can depend on:

- CSC or FSC?
- which kind of content element (CE) do you use? (be sure to enhance the rendering of that CE)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Good to know that the example is outdated.
I'll check the link.
I'm using FSC on the standard textmedia element.

Comment: then your problem starts at the basic TS definition as FSC does not know a CE type `text` but `textmedia`. Also the parsefunc in FSC is `lib.parseFunc` or `lib.parseFunc_RTE` and not inside `tt_content.textmedia`.

Comment: Good info.
So far i managed to get simple replacement to make text inside tag bold just for test:
`# imagebox tags
lib.parseFunc_RTE.allowTags := addToList(imagebox)
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.imagebox = TEXT
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.imagebox {
  stdWrap.current = 1
  stdWrap.wrap = <span style="font-weight: bold;"> | </span>
}
`
Now i just need to see if i can use RECORDS with some formatting or USER type instead of TEXT to insert properly formatted content.